URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
After creating adding some content on my xml file (Kotlin), I am getting this error everytime I try to run an app:
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@f1a9cc0.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1d720bbc.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5690bc5d.
Another hint at the orgin of the error suggest to look at this file:
It seems this error is related to :..\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
This file does show 2 warnings for the first line:
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

When hovering over the warning part, I can see the following message: URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs), which comes with a few options:

Add xsi:schemaLocation
Fetch external resource
Ignore external resource

I am fairly new to mobile development. What is the right appraoch to this error? Should I ignore it? I am unsure what provoked this error in the first place.
Any advice?
Edit: Forgot to mention, this file is autogenerated and seems it would be bad idea to alter it.
